Feminina "area" con el masculino articulo "el"
Me sorprende descubrir que la palabra femenina "area" debe escribirse con el masculino articulo. La explicación que encontré parece ser aún más sorprendente: "Área es un sustantivo femenino que se escribe con a tónica inicial por lo que el artículo que le acompaña debe ser el;"
¿Cómo es que ardilla se escribe con "la"?
¿Qué otros ejemplos de este tipo debería conocer?
Edit: The question is different from the suggested by the details contained in the answer (the link with tables of example words)

Did you really expect me to know all the similar words without the reference I was given here as a part of the answer?

Nadie dijo que tuvieras la culpa de nada. Pero la política es marcar las preguntas como duplicadas y remitirla a la primera pregunta que se hizo. Si así y todo tras leer te quedan dudas no dudes en vovler a preguntar, pero sé específico. Saludos.

What difference is there between: el agua fría and un area bonita. Same thing. These are a case-by-case basis.

If I could upvote the answer given by Javier Bezos, I would have done it by now for sure. Because I find it useful in the context of comparison with the suggested older post about "agua", which misses the link proposed by Javier. Unfortunately, I am a newbie here, so have no rating yet to upvote. I leave the decision to the discretion of local moderators, who are seemingly hesitant to recognize that Javier's answer is useful. So once the question is closed, noone will be able to find Javier's link.

I am hopeful that the real reason for closing the question has nothing to do with my Russian IP address.

Have no fear. We don't discriminte against people in that manner.

@JimmyBionic The only reason I know about your IP address is that you just mentioned it.  So any actions by me and everyone else had nothing to do with that.  Across all Stack Overflow sites we're pretty well egalitarian when it comes to genuine questions.  What generally gets removed is only abuse and spam.  Also closing a question doesn't remove it, so Javier's links won't be lost.  And technically while there are official admins, everyone here is a moderator (once you have enough reputation points)

Estrictamente no es el artículo masculino, sino una derivación distinta del latín illa, que normalmente evolucionó a la (tomando la parte del final), pero que en las palabras que empiezan por a tónica acabó evolucionado a el (tomando la parte del principio). Aquí tienes más información: https://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/la.

No es el artículo masculino....¿ qué ?

@tac  los eruditos dicen: ¿ las palabras que empiezan por a tónica acabó evolucionado a el o *las palabras que empiezan por a tónica acabaron evolucionado a el ? Estás muy agresiva.

Si la respuesta va dirigida "a eruditos intelectuales" ¿ porqué votaste para cerrarla ?

@Lambie Antídotos contra la terquedad y ofuscación. 1. Los eruditos decimos que ‘EN las palabras que empiezan por a tónica (el artículo) acabó evolucionado a el’, ay Dios; cuándo vamos a aprender a prestar más atención a lo que está redactado? 2. La pregunta está fuera de lugar, es un duplicado; eso no tiene nada que ver con que se pueda dar una respuesta mirífica, pero no se juzgan las preguntas por las respuestas ni viceversa. (argumentos irrefutables, imposible un punchline más sarpado que el que acabo de tirar)

@Lambie ja ja, siga participando
